# Do-While Loop continuously prints when Program is ran

Tags: java, loops, do-while

I have the following code used in my program:

```
do {
    if (numOfItems == 3 || numOfItems == 5 || numOfItems == 7 || numOfItems == 9) {
        addItems(numOfItems);

    } else {
        System.out.println("That number is out of range.");
        System.out.println("Please choose an odd number in the range of [1, 10] exclusively:");
        numOfItems = scan.nextInt();
    }
} while (numOfItems != 3 || numOfItems != 5 || numOfItems != 7 || numOfItems != 9);
```

which, when run, keeps repeating the method which I only want to happen once. How to I make the loop keep repeating for validation, but only run the method once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

`while (numOfItems != 3 || numOfItems != 5 || numOfItems != 7 || numOfItems != 9);`

with

`while (numOfItems != 3 && numOfItems != 5 && numOfItems != 7 && numOfItems != 9);`

**Update**

From your comment to the answer, it looks like you need to do something like following:

```
do {
    numOfItems = scan.nextInt();
    if (numOfItems == 3 || numOfItems == 5 || numOfItems == 7 || numOfItems == 9) {
        addItems(numOfItems);

    } else {
        System.out.println("That number is out of range.");
        System.out.println("Please choose an odd number in the range of [1, 10] exclusively:");

    }
} while (numOfItems != 3 && numOfItems != 5 && numOfItems != 7 && numOfItems != 9);
```

However, you can optimize this to something like following:

```
while ((numOfItems = scan.nextInt() != 3) && numOfItems != 5 && numOfItems != 7 && numOfItems != 9) {

            System.out.println("That number is out of range.");
            System.out.println("Please choose an odd number in the range of [1, 10] exclusively:");
}

addItems(numOfItems);
```

Comment: That fixes the solution, however, now it doesn't validate correctly. If I enter in a number not 3, 5, 7, or 9 then enter one of those numbers, the method doesn't run?

Comment: Isn't that a desirable behavior? Keep on running the loop until the user enters one of those 4 numbers? If this is not the desired behavior, you need to provide more explanation

Comment: @Kooba:  What do you mean by "the method."  The code excerpt you provided does not call any method.

Comment: @VHS Your first solution fixed my problem. Not sure how exactly but it works optimally now, thanks!

Comment: @Kooba, glad that I could be of help.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to correct

```
while (numOfItems != 3 || numOfItems != 5 || numOfItems != 7 || numOfItems != 9);
```

since, it would *always be **true***.

You can get rid of this(`do..while`) condition if you always want to execute the `do{...}` block of statements. ("...which I only want to happen once")